# Unexpected behaviour with RX Subscribe - subscribe() & awaiting task completion :~|

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I have the following block of code that when run I expected to consume the blocking collection and within the Subscribe() action perform some async activity that is awaited on before RX moves onto the next entry in the observer sequence.

What actually happened is that all the entries are processed (or appear to be) in parallel.

The code as it stands at the moment is as follows!

```
    uploadQueues[workspaceId] //BlockingCollection<FileEvent>>
    .GetConsumingEnumerable()
    .ToObservable()
    .SubscribeOn(new TaskPoolScheduler(new TaskFactory()))
    .Subscribe(
      async fileEvent =>
       {
          //process file event
          Debug.WriteLine($"Upload queue processor 1: {fileEvent.Event} | {fileEvent.SourcePath} => {fileEvent.DestPath}");
          await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

       })
```

Any pointers in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.. also wondering if a instead of using RX I just simply spawn a long running TPL task that consumes from the blocking collection!

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your Rx query is the `async/await` part, because you aren't handling or taking care of the `SynchronizationContext.Current`

But they're other problems with your entire code.

Staring in the `SubscribeOn`, `TaskPoolSchedule` is `IDisposable` class, you should implement and dispose that properly.

Also, when you are using `ToObservable()` method it doesn't use any `IScheduler` - check for details [here](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#FromIEnumerable). You could specify a `EventLoopScheduler` to guarantee that just one single thread/resource is going to be used to process
(although is not necessary because the `GetConsumingEnumerable` is already locking one thread just to consume).

If you just want to simulate a delay, the best way to do is:

```
        enumerableItems.ToObservable()
            .Select(a => Observable.Return(a).DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))) 
            .Concat() // Keep push order
            .Subscribe(
                fileEvent =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(fileEvent);
                });
```

`DelaySubscription` is a little bit more efficient than `Delay` just be aware, that the delay is not synchronous, so probably would will end up with in another `Thread.ThreadId`, but that doesn't matter because the order and the sequence is going to be kept.

Now if you want to use async/await with Rx and keep it single threat, that is a problem for another question...

Comment: Thanks for the response... I'm still learning with RX so it's good to see why I'm going wrong :)

I might be delaying with async/await in the subscribe... but that is just to mimic activity in there... that their subscribe will be calling out to async/await code.

My real concern was the async/await and processing the stream in sequence.. maybe I need to also look at how I ask questions too :(

Comment: Ideally you would not be calling out to async/await code in your subscribe method. Instead, consider the result of the Async/Await call to be just another async sequence and compose it into your query pipeline.

Comment: hmm.. yup that makes sense even though the await tasks are likely network activity that I'm ultimately going to throw the response away for!

Comment: But you still care about cancellation and error support. You loose that in the subscribe handlers

Answer (score 2):

[Upvoted @J.Lennon's answer]

Welcome to using Rx. As J.Lennon mentioned above, there is some improvement suggested to your code above.

As with any code synchronous or asynchronous we want to consider our resources and how we ensure that we clean then up afterwards. We also need to consider how to handle exceptions. In addition to these concerns, when working with asynchrony (and therefore concurrency) we have the additional concern of cancellation. We should provide the ability to cancel the operation and we should also make sure that cancellation does what the consumer would expect.

While I think that Rx is not the best suited tool for reading off queues (see http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#Wont), if you really wanted to force Rx into the picture then you may also want to be sure that you meet the above concerns..

Code below uses

- `CancellationToken`s to allow the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` to be cancelled (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395014(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `EventLoopScheduler` to ensure a singe thread is dedicated to processing the queue. This also makes it serialized. (http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#EventLoopScheduler)
- moving the async work you had in your subscriber into the query pipeline where it belongs.
- J.Lennon's `Concat` tip from above to ensure the the async work you are doing is also serialised. (http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Concat)
- All error handling will now be the sole concern of the final subscriber (the code that subscribes to this method). Here you will use an `OnError` handler. However this leads me back to why I dont like Rx for processing queues. What should you do in a failure? Attempt to re-read the message and fall into an infinite loop, or drop it on the floor and pretend it didn't happen? (http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html#Subscribe)

Sample code

```
IDictionary<string, BlockingCollection<object>> uploadQueues = new Dictionary<string, BlockingCollection<Object>>();
public IObservable<object> ListenToQueueEvents(string workspaceId)
{
    //Not sure what the return value is here, using `Object` as a place holder.
    //  Note that we are using an overload that takes a `CancellationToken`
    return Observable.Create<object>((obs, ct) =>
    {
        var els = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts)
        {
            IsBackground = true,//? or false? Should it stop the process from terminating if it still running?
            Name = $"{workspaceId}Processor"
        });
        var subscription = uploadQueues[workspaceId] //BlockingCollection<FileEvent>>
            .GetConsumingEnumerable(ct) //Allow cancellation while wating for next item
            .ToObservable(els)  //Serialise onto a single thread.
            .Select(evt=>TheAsyncThingIWasDoingInTheSubscribe(evt).ToObservable())
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe(obs);
        //You could try to dispose of the els (EventLoopScheduler), But I have had issues doing so in the past. 
        //  Leaving as Background should allow it to die (but non deterministically) :-(
        return Task.FromResult(subscription);
    });
}
private static Task<object> TheAsyncThingIWasDoingInTheSubscribe(object evt)
{
    //The return of the async thing you were doing in the subscribe
    return Task.FromResult(new Object());
}
```

Comment: Cool.. thanks!

I know there is some stuff I could tidy in the code example such as the cancellation token etc (I emitted it to make the code leaner as it has no direct effect on the async not being awaited - I leave it in next time - ha!)

As you might have noticed from my initial question, I was playing around with the idea of a long running tpl task (with a cancellation token!) to process entries off the queue!

Being new to RX... I had a feeling (guess it was wrong) that the RX route might be more elegant but it looks like all the extra plumbing needed is bonkers!